# Will and going to

Tags: questions, will-vs-going-to

I want to ask shall I use "will" or " be going to " when the sentence appears the word "if"?

I tried " will" in the sentence:
      She...(fail) her test if she still does not study.

Comment: Do you suspect that using "will" is incorrect? Why?

Answer (score 1):

The use of **if** does not effect the meaning or usage in your examples.

> She **will** fail if she does not study.
>   She **is going to** fail if she does not study.

A subtle nuance is "**will**" makes it sound more *definite* that something happens.

Comment: I don't really see any difference in potential with either "will" or "going to".  Both imply that something is *likely*, but how likely is something you pick up from context, and is often based on personal opinion.